# Some space before chart bar

Tags: c#, charts, mschart

My code has three bars and i need to make some space before them: it should start with some specific value, not 0;
[What I have now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kb78M.png)
[What I want to get (example)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlFD1.png)

Here is my code:

```
        var ch = new Chart();
        ch.Series.Clear();

        var cha = new ChartArea();
        ch.ChartAreas.Add(cha);

        var datePlanSeries = new Series {ChartType = SeriesChartType.Bar };
        var dateAgreedSeries = new Series { ChartType = SeriesChartType.Bar };
        var dateFactSeries = new Series { ChartType = SeriesChartType.Bar };

        datePlanSeries.Points.AddY(durationPlan);
        dateAgreedSeries.Points.AddY(durationAgreed);
        dateFactSeries.Points.AddY(durationFact);

        // And what should I add to each series to "move" it?

        ch.Series.Add(datePlanSeries);
        ch.Series.Add(dateAgreedSeries);
        ch.Series.Add(dateFactSeries);
```

Comment: Bars (and columns) always start at 0. If you want to move some to the right you can use chart type StackedBar and add transparent dummy series datapoints  before the each normal series point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a chart type called [Range Bar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456745.aspx). Each datapoint takes 2 Y-values, think from-Y and to-Y. So instead of:

> ```
> var datePlanSeries = new Series {ChartType = SeriesChartType.Bar };
>
> ...
>
> datePlanSeries.Points.AddY(durationPlan);
> ```

You use:

```
var datePlanSeries = new Series { ChartType = SeriesChartType.RangeBar };

...

datePlanSeries.Points.Add(1, 10); // from Y = 1, to Y = 10
```